# How to add a document with user.uid as id to a collection in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The first time user logs in with Google Auth provider I want to add a `document` with `user.uid` as id to "Users" `collection`.

If I use `setDoc` to add the `document`,

```
  await setDoc(doc(db, "UsersData", user.uid), {
    username: "",
    isAdmin: false,
    user: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))
  });
```

and the user changes the username, done with `updateDoc`,  this ☝️ properties will be merged with the old ones everytime the user logs in.

I tried `addDoc`,

```
  await addDoc(collection(db, "UsersData", user.uid), {
    username: "",
    isAdmin: false,
    user: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user))
  });
```

but I get this error `Document references must have an even number of segments UserData... has 3`, how can I solve this?

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve.  Why doesn't updateDoc work for your case?  That's exactly what you're supposed to use if you want to change the fields of an exising document.  addDoc is only used for adding a new document with a random ID.  Please edit the question to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @DougStevenson `updateDoc` works for changing the username, but if the user changes `username: "John"` and then logs in again, username will be `username: ""`. Thats the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You're probably using `onAuthStateChanges()` you need to check are user exists, then assign data. You're probably assigning data when the user is not logged in.

Comment: @Mises Thats exactly what I'm doing, I'm using useAuthState from react-firebase-hooks but I do check if user exists with useEffect.

Comment: In a question you have hard coded `username: "",` are you sure you don't have it some ware in your code ?

Comment: @Mises Yes I hard coded it to begin with, but I now I changed it to usernameSet `boolean` to check if username is set, but `setDoc` keep merging it with the initial value even with `merge` on true or false.

Comment: Hard refresh browser. Browser, probably using old code. SHIFT + F5 to hard refresh.

Comment: @Mises Still doesn't work. My code currently: https://i.gyazo.com/282f5eadcee3813df6fadc52e9414707.png

Comment: You can edit your question and past code, not image in it. Are you getting any value from input, did you check it ?

Comment: @Mises Yes, I can see it in Firestore db and it's visible in client side, but when I log out and log in again it merges with the initial values from `setDoc`

Answer (score 4):

Function `addDoc()` is, to adding new documents with auto generated ID. This function got just two variables, you can pass in collection reference and data. There are two ways to update documents. Using `updateDoc()` and `setDoc()`.

Using `setDoc()` function will create a new file if it not exists and update if it has option merge to true.

```js
const docRef = doc(db, 'userData', user.uid)
const result = await setDoc(docRef, { name: user.displayName}, { merge: true })
```

Comment: So `merge` is true on default?

Comment: @Mintee Option `{ merge: true }` will force `setDoc()` function to update fields you pass as data and lave other as they were. It works same as `updateDoc()` function.